# docker: run mysql container with specific uid:gid

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

i am building an app stack where mysql is one of the services. I want all services to run as uid 1000:1000, so i dont have any trouble with permissions on the host system.

Now i have problems doing this with the official mysql docker image.

Here is what i do:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
RUN addgroup --gid 1000 app \
 && adduser --gecos "" --home /home/app --shell /bin/bash --disabled-password --uid 1000 --gid 1000 app \
 && adduser app mysql \
 && adduser mysql app
RUN chown -R app:app /var/lib/mysql && chmod -R g+wrx /var/lib/mysql
COPY mysql.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/99-docker.cnf
COPY .my.cnf /home/app/.my.cnf
COPY .root.cnf /root/.my.cnf
RUN chmod 0664 /etc/mysql/conf.d/99-docker.cnf
USER app
EXPOSE 3306
```

And the service in my compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    user: 1000:1000
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
```

The env file contains some vars for mysql:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_DATABASE=app
MYSQL_USER=app
MYSQL_PASSWORD=app
```

the .my.cnf files contain credentials

the mysql config contains some cache settings, sql-mode and:

```
[mysqld]
user=app
```

when starting the service with: `docker-compose up --build mysql` i get the following error:

```
mysql_1  | Initializing database
mysql_1  | mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
mysql_1  | 2020-04-09T11:11:25.664285Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1  | 2020-04-09T11:11:25.664345Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
mysql_1  | 2020-04-09T11:11:25.666725Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
mysql_1  | 2020-04-09T11:11:25.666744Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
mysql_1  | 
pixel3_mysql_1 exited with code 1
```

When running `docker-compose run mysql bash` and inspecting the files i see, that the /var/lib/mysql directory is root-owned.

In the documentation (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) it says i can run the image with another user but to me it seems this is not possible.

Do i have to override the entrypoint to chown the directories over and over again or what is my mistake?

Comment: The image documentation you link to suggests you shouldn't need a custom image, just the `user:` setting you show and for the data directory to be writeable.  Does running the stock `mysql:5.7` image work?  (Are there settings besides the alternate-user setting in the `my.cnf` that matter?)  (And, are you on a Mac or have you otherwise configured user namespace remapping?)